# how to convert DAT file to pdf in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to convert a DAT file to PDF in c# without using database.

currently I am using Crystal Report , and i am inserting  data's of multiple dat file in database and converting into pdf from the database table.

now the issue is there are same records in multiple dat file while inserting bulk data's of multiple dat file it is duplicating records in database as well as in pdf. 
please help me to achieve.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Did you try transactions in SQL? It blocks the tabel so that only one person can change value at a time.

Comment: I don't understand: what is the input, what is the output you're trying to create, how are you using Crystal Report to do it (show us some code) and what exactly is going wrong with what you've tried?

Comment: sorry,please check my question now

Answer (score 0):

DAT-files are often program-specific files and can not be easily imported and converted.

Comment: i have dat file in my local system  and want to convert each dat file to pdf from local server without using database